# SSH issue when connection MySQL workbench to vagrant

Tags: mysql, ssh, vagrant, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to connect to my vagrant MySQL server using MySQL workbench. It shows some error as shown in the image.

[image: error screenshot]

The workbench error log is pasted below.

```
17:34:50 [INF][     SSH tunnel]: Existing SSH tunnel not found, opening new one
17:34:50 [INF][     SSH tunnel]: Opening SSH tunnel to 127.0.0.1:2222
17:34:50 [ERR][   sshtunnel.py]: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/mysql-workbench/sshtunnel.py", line 231, in _connect_ssh
    look_for_keys=has_key, allow_agent=has_key)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 337, in connect
    self._auth(username, password, pkey, key_filenames, allow_agent, look_for_keys)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 528, in _auth
    raise saved_exception
AuthenticationException: Authentication failed.
17:34:50 [ERR][     SSH tunnel]: Authentication error opening SSH tunnel: Authentication error. Please check that your username and password are correct and try again.
```

`vagrant up` command output is pasted below

```
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 6216 (adapter 1)
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
```

The command `vagrant ssh` works fine in terminal. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you ssh directly to 127.0.0.1:2222 as the vagrant user with the expected password (should be `vagrant` if the box is set up as Vagrant recommends)?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Nope. It shows `ssh: Could not resolve hostname 127.0.0.1:2222: Name or service not known`. I've added the `vagrant up` command output

Comment: These sound like different issues. The error in your question is when it is connecting to the box but then failing to authenticate. The error in your comment is when there is no connectivity to the box. Are you sure the VM is running?

Comment: yes, it is. I can access the url via browser and ssh via terminal.

Comment: As @MartinKalcok mentioned, try specifying the port with the -p option to ssh and checking if you can connect with a normal (non Vagrant) ssh terminal

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I've tried the ssh using -p and it works. But the default password doesn't works.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I've fixed the issue after googling. Posted it as answer for those who face the same issue in future. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you run `vagrant ssh-config` it will show which key it is using. It does not normally use the `.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key` but a key in the project directory like `.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key`.

If you specify that key in the MySQL connection panel you should be able to logon without having to add another key to the vm.

Comment: You saved my day! Thanks

Comment: I was using the wrong key based on other examples (insecure_private_key in .vagrant.d). This solved the issue, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Regarding error you mention in comments:
When using ssh you don't specify port like this

```
ssh 127.0.0.1:2222
```

You must use option -p

```
ssh 127.0.0.1 -p 2222
```

Comment: This is supposed to be a comment. Not an answer.

Comment: Sorry, my rep is not high enough to comment. Just wanted to point you in right direction.

Answer (score 2):

After some googling, I got it working by adding my ssh public key to vagrant `authorized_keys` file. Steps Below.

1. [generate ssh keys](https://askubuntu.com/a/61560) for your machine
2. copy your public key from `/home/{username}/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` file
3. open `vagrant ssh` in termial
4. use some editor to edit `/home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys`(eg: `nano /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys`)
5. paste your public key to the end of that file and save

done!